# Perl: autovivification doesn't create array in hash

Tags: arrays, perl, autovivification

I have this segment of a perl script:

```
my $thread_count = 20

my %QUEUES;
my $current_queue=0;

while(defined($INPUT[$cnt]))
{
        while (my @instance = $q1->fetchrow_array)
        {
                my $walk = "string";
                push @{$QUEUES{$current_queue}},$walk;
                $current_queue=($current_queue+1)%$thread_count;
        }

        while (my @instance = $q2->fetchrow_array) {
                my $walk = "string";
                push @{$QUEUES{$current_queue}},$walk;
                $current_queue=($current_queue+1)%$thread_count;
        }
}
```

I was trying to push commands in an array, which I decided to keep in a hash because I thought I could keep my life easy and not do `if(!defined($QUEUES[$current_queue]))$QUEUES[$current_queue]=[];`

I used `Data::Dumper` and a regular for loop and found that nothing was defined for any key in $QUEUE, 0 to $thread_count-1. Isn't this a textbook auto-vivification usage? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That code will not run. Why don't you make a [mcve] that displays the same problem you're experiencing?

Comment: I'm also not sure what you think is supposed to be happening with `($current_queue+1)%$thread_count`...

Comment: @MattJacob: `$current_queue=($current_queue+1)%$thread_count;` increments `$current_queue` by one modulo `$thread_count`. There's surely nothing weird there, is there? That said, I'm unable to reproduce the problem as described, so I'm voting to put this question on hold until an actual example demonstrating the unwanted behavior is provided.

Comment: (Also, I'm not sure why the OP is defining `%QUEUES` as a hash, and then indexing it with integers from 0 to 19. Surely an array would be better for that? But at least that shouldn't affect the autovivification behavior in any way.)

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Yes, you're right. (And it's late in my timezone.) Whenever I see `%$` in Perl without a space, I immediately think that someone is trying to dereference a hash reference.

Comment: If you're using threads be sure to look into [the DBI docs on threads](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#Threads-and-Thread-Safety). Otherwise I suspect your queries are returning nothing so the loops are never being run. Put a print or increment a counter inside the while loop to find out.

Comment: @Ilmari Karonen I answered your question here: "I was trying to push commands in an array, which I decided to keep in a hash because I thought I could keep my life easy and not do if(!defined($QUEUES[$current_queue]))$QUEUES[$current_queue]=[];"  edited for grammar.

Comment: @jasondancks: Ah, OK. I guess you didn't realize that arrays autovivify in Perl, too. Anyway, the code inside your loops works just fine. As Schwern notes above, most likely your loops never run in the first place, either because `$INPUT[$cnt]` is undefined, or because `fetchrow_array` never returns a non-empty list. But without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), we can't really tell why that might be happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
push @{ $QUEUES{$current_queue} }, $walk;
```

is equivalent to

```
push @{ $QUEUES{$current_queue} //= [] }, $walk;
```

If that statement got executed when `$QUEUES{$current_queue}` didn't exist, `$QUEUES{$current_queue}` would get created, and it would be assigned a reference to an array with one element (a copy of `$walk`).

So, if `%QUEUES` is empty, then the `push` statements were never executed.

Comment: Sorry for the long delay. Thank for your insightful answer. It turns out after some investigation that the loop in fact was never executing because `fetchrow_array` never returned anything. I still can't figure out why, or what I can do about it. Still, your answer was very helpful. thanks.